# Why is NSFileManager not working properly?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsfilemanager

My app downloads files from the internet and stores them using `NSFileManager` everything seems to be working until I rerun the app using xCode (I can't use the files, remove them-....)

But if I didn't rerun it with xCode and used it normally on my phone it doesn't seem to have this issue. (example: I can play the downloaded mp3)

Here is some code from my project

```
// Creates a new path for the download
func createFilePathForDownload(filePath: String) -> NSURL? {
    let searchForDoucumentDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = searchForDoucumentDirectory.first
    
    return documentDirectory!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filePath)
}

// After the download is done downloading this NSURLSessionDownloadTaskDelegate method will excute
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    for (_, downloadInProgress) in allDownloads.enumerate() {
        if downloadTask.isEqual(downloadInProgress.downloadTask) {
            
            let newPath = createFilePathForDownload((downloadInProgress.downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename!)!)
            
            downloadInProgress.filePathTemp = location
            downloadInProgress.filePath = newPath
            
            if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(location.path!) == true) {
                print("\(location.path!) does exist")
            }
            
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(location, toURL: downloadInProgress.filePath)
            } catch {
                
            }
            
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(location)
            } catch {
                
            }
            
            if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(downloadInProgress.filePath.path!) == true) {
                print("\(downloadInProgress.filePath.path!) does exist")
            }
            
            downloadInProgress.downloadData = nil
            downloadInProgress.downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.Finished
            delegate?.downloadHasBeenFinished!(downloadInProgress)
            saveChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

Using something like this will not work

```
func playMediaAtPath(path: NSURL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: path)
    self.moviePlayer.player = player
    self.presentViewController(self.moviePlayer, animated: true) {
        self.moviePlayer.player?.play()
    }
}
```

The app size and output indicate that the files are still exist but not opened.

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B5BE8F6-C71A-4BDC-86E5-3132AD9330B8/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_5rFN0V.tmp does exist
>
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B5BE8F6-C71A-4BDC-86E5-3132AD9330B8/Documents/OneRepublic - Wherever I Go.mp3 does exist

Comment: NSLog the document path when you run and re-run and compare to see if they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, the issue seems that every time xCode builds and installs the Application, xCode will give a new path for the application.

So a workaround this I used the downloaded file path last component like this.

```
let newpath = createFilePathForDownload(path.lastPathComponent!)
```

this will return the new path for the downloaded file.

So to make the last part of the code in the description work I used something like this:

```
func playMediaAtPath(path: NSURL) {
    let newpath = sharedStore.filePathForDownload(path.lastPathComponent!)
    print(newpath?.path)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: newpath!)
    self.moviePlayer.player = player
    self.presentViewController(self.moviePlayer, animated: true) {
        self.moviePlayer.player?.play()
    }
}
```